# Azure runbook using python to connect to Sql databae

Tags: python, azure, runbook

I am creating an azure runbook to connect to a sql database to make some queries .

I was trying to import one of two libraries : pymssql , pyodbc but the machine runs the runbook does not have that library.

Do you have any other idea to make some queries to sql database , or install these two libraries on that machine.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you have any other idea to make some queries to sql database , or
>   install these two libraries on that machine.

As a workaround, we can use PowerShell to run sql query, here is the example:

```
    $SqlServer = "jasontest321.database.windows.net"
    $SqlServerPort = "1433"
    $Database = "jasonsqltest"
    $Table = "dbc"
    $SqlCredentialAsset = "sql"
    $SqlCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $SqlCredentialAsset 
    if ($SqlCredential -eq $null) 
        { 
            throw "Could not retrieve '$SqlCredentialAsset' credential asset. Check that you created this first in the Automation service." 
        }   
    $SqlUsername = $SqlCredential.UserName 
    $SqlPass = $SqlCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password 
    $Conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=tcp:$SqlServer,$SqlServerPort;Database=$Database;User ID=$SqlUsername;Password=$SqlPass;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;")

    $Conn.Open() 
    $Cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("insert into dbc(name,age)values('jason2','ba')", $Conn) 
    $Cmd.CommandTimeout=120 
    $Ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet 
    $Da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($Cmd)
    [void]$Da.fill($Ds)
    $Ds.Tables.Column1
    $Conn.Close()
```

About the `$SqlCredentialAsset = "sql"`, we should create credentials in Azure automation account, like this:
[image]

Here is the runbook result:

[image]

More information about, please refer to this [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-use-a-SQL-Command-be77f9d2).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: I can't install  pymssql , pyodbc to runbook, as a workaround, we can use powershell to execute SQL, please check my answer, please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: sorry for my late reply. Your solution is very helpful to me. Yeah, python is one of my primary language while power shell is new. Starting with power shell is a bit difficult for me , and your message help me al lot. I am doing your way

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler solution to that. Pip library is already installed in azure python runbook. You can use this to install those libraries.

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'pymssql'])
```

Worked fine for me.