# Can a Python Runbook in Azure Automation run a SQL Query?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have a SQL Database and an Automation Account in Microsoft Azure. Each day I employ a scraping bot that stores two strings of data. To do this, I use a website called scraping-bot.io. After obtaining the strings, I run a SQL query in SSMS to store them in a table manually.

My goal is to use a runbook with my Automation Account to scrape the website and then run a SQL query to store the strings in the table.

I'm able to do the scraping with a Python runbook in my Automation Account as such:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.scraping-bot.io/rawHtmlPage.html'
username = 'xxxx'
apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

apiUrl = "https://www.banpais.hn/barradolar.php"

payload = json.dumps({"url": url})
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json"}

response = requests.request("POST", apiUrl, data=payload, auth=(username, apiKey), headers=headers)

COMPRA = response.text.partition('var d_compra = ')[2][0:(response.text.partition('var d_compra = ')[2].find(';'))]
VENTA = response.text.partition('var d_venta = ')[2][0:(response.text.partition('var d_compra = ')[2].find(';'))]
```

Where COMPRA and VENTA are the strings I am scraping.

I have no problem with this task, however, I am having trouble understanding how to run a SQL query to store the data in the table from there.

I have tried adding this:

```
import pyodbc
server = 'tcp:xxxxxxx.database.windows.net'
database = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
table = '[dbo].[xxxxxxx]'
username = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
password = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; SERVER=' + server + '; DATABASE=' + database + '; UID=' + username + '; PWD=' + password)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("QUERY HERE")
```

However, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Temp\fdejt30f.zha\eae7fa25-4541-40d1-bc95-83642c705b27", line 5, in <module>    import pyodbcModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

After playing a bit I was able to pip install pyodbc, but was met with another error telling me there was no 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' installed. I'm stumped.

Is there a way to run a SQL query with a python runbook in Azure Automation Account?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for helping me out. Haven't been able to try it, but I'm sure it will help. As soon as I get to try it and find a solution I'll keep anyone looking for an answer to this posted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To run a SQL query with a python runbook in Azure Automation Account, you can try following 3 approaches:

**1. [Host the script on Azure HTTP trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62526708/15969115)** as answered by Jim Xu:

```
async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    server = 'jimtestsql.database.windows.net'
    database = 'test'
    username = 'jim@hanxia.onmicrosoft.com'
    password = 'Wdsr199545#'
    driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT Top(1) * FROM [dbo].[StarWars]")
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    return func.HttpResponse(str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
```

**2. [Use Hybrid Worker Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker)** as [answered by SwathiDhanwada-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/331687/azure-automation-account-python-3-runbook-sql-serv.html)

**3. [Use Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46786120/15969115)** as answered by Jason Ye:

```
$SqlServer = "jasontest321.database.windows.net"
    $SqlServerPort = "1433"
    $Database = "jasonsqltest"
    $Table = "dbc"
    $SqlCredentialAsset = "sql"
    $SqlCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $SqlCredentialAsset 
    if ($SqlCredential -eq $null) 
        { 
            throw "Could not retrieve '$SqlCredentialAsset' credential asset. Check that you created this first in the Automation service." 
        }   
    $SqlUsername = $SqlCredential.UserName 
    $SqlPass = $SqlCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password 
    $Conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=tcp:$SqlServer,$SqlServerPort;Database=$Database;User ID=$SqlUsername;Password=$SqlPass;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;")

    $Conn.Open() 
    $Cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("insert into dbc(name,age)values('jason2','ba')", $Conn) 
    $Cmd.CommandTimeout=120 
    $Ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet 
    $Da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($Cmd)
    [void]$Da.fill($Ds)
    $Ds.Tables.Column1
    $Conn.Close()
```

You can refer to [Unable to connect to Azure SQL Database via Python ODBC Driver Issue feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59750581/unable-to-connect-to-azure-sql-database-via-python-odbc-driver-issue) and feedback to [Install "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" on the Python Runbook Virtual Machines](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/43048677-install-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server-on-the-pyt)

Comment: I wasn't able to do either of the options in the answer. Either way accepting it as solved for other users to see it.